# how to append an element as a first child in jquery

Tags: jquery

lets say i have html something like this..

```
<ul id="leftNavigation">
  <table id="leftNavTable"><tr><td>blablabla</td></tr><table>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

what i want to do is when i click on any li, then that table should get hide and another table should get appended in place of that table.lets say that table is

```
<table id="Selected"><tr><td>blablabla</td></tr><table>
```

how to do it in jQuery.

i tried in this way but its adding as a last child of ul.

```
$('#leftNavigation').append('<table id="Selected"><tr><td>blablabla</td></tr><table>')
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `.prepend()` or `.prependTo()` instead.

Check [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

### Additional notes

But based on what you're trying to accomplish you should maybe rather use [DOM replacement functionality](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-replacement/).

### Beware

Adding anything else than `LI` inside an `UL` or `OL` is invalid HTML.

I suggest you add an additional `LI`, give it some `ID` or CSS `class` and then manipulate its content.

Comment: thanks...Robert...i know that this not a right html but due to some requirements i am forced to do this...

Comment: @Vivek: Fine by me. If valid HTML is not a requirement and doesn't bother you, then go ahead and use it.